# how to avoid "header" interfaces and use autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I read a lot about best practices for design.  Recently, I came across [this article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/12/02/Interfacesarenotabstractions/) by Mark Seemann.  In this article he states

> "Do you extract interfaces from your classes to enable loose coupling?
>   If so, you probably have a 1:1 relationship between your interfaces
>   and the concrete classes that implement them. That's probably not a
>   good sign, and violates the Reused Abstractions Principle (RAP). I've
>   been guilty of this and didn't like the result."

Now, I have been using Autofac for many, many years for DI.  I've noticed that in order to actually implement a concrete class as an interface I basically must violate this "principle" by creating interfaces for each class that I will need to either swap out the implementation in testing or inject into other services.

An example of this looks like:

```
builder.RegisterType<AcknowledgementRepository>()
            .As<IAcknowledgementRepository>();

        builder.RegisterType<ChangeLogRepository>()
            .As<IChangeLogRepository>();

        builder.RegisterType<HistoryCycleRepository>()
            .As<IHistoryCycleRepository>();
```

This is a very common pattern that I see used very frequently.  But, it seems like it might be an indication of bad design.

I'm interested in how others avoid creating these "header" interfaces, it seems like the solution might have to do with using .AsImplementedInterfaces(), but I have not played around with it enough.

Edit: I should note that the repositories above inherit from IGenericRepository, but also extend it in many cases.

Comment: I was able to remove 90% of the interfaces by using something like `   builder.RegisterType<HistoryCycleRepository>().As<IRepository<HistoryCycle>>();`  I'm going to keep looking for commonality in my interfaces as I move forward.

Comment: Although it doesn't address the RAP, [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) approaches the use of those 1:1 interfaces from the perspective of the SOLID principles, which is something you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by simply refactoring my code base through the following steps:

All of my repositories were implementing IRepostory and inheriting the BaseRepository class, and very few of them actually overrode any functionality in the base repository. So instead of creating a bunch of I___Repositories, I simply used autofac in this way.

`builder.RegisterType<MemberRepository>().As<IRepository<Member>>();`

Then I just had to change my injections to look like this:

```
    private readonly IRepository<Member> _memberRepo;
    //constructor
    public MyService(IRepostiory<Member> memberRepo)
    {   
        _memberRepo = memberRepo;
    }
```

I still had some additional functionality in a few repos and realized those methods actually indicated that one repository served as more of a repoistory of data dictionaries.  So, I made another interface called `ICustomDictionaryLookup`

Then when I registered my services in autofac for this one I registered the concrete implementation for each interface.

`builder.RegisterType<DictionaryRepostiory>().As<IRepository<CustomDictionary>>();`

`builder.RegisterType<DictionaryRepostiory>().As<ICustomDicionary>();`

This is great because it separates the abstractions and allows me flexibility to pick and choose which concrete implementations will fulfill specific functionality.  Now there is no reason that I couldn't register the DictionaryRepository to serve as the CRUD and another ICustomDictionary that is completely different.

Methods that only depend upon the ability to retrieve a custom dictionary and not perform CRUD operations on the dictionary table don't need to even know that CRUD functionality exists in the base class since it is irrelevant.

I'm glad I went down this path as my code is much better.